# Unable to add and use external jars to maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I need to add a third part jar to my maven project. In my local, I installed the jar using the command `mvn install:install-file -DlocalRepositoryPath=/home/sandesha-uat/.m2/repository -DcreateChecksum=true -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/home/******/third-party.jar -DgroupId=com.xyz.abc -DartifactId=somefunction -Dversion=1.0` and added this as a dependency in one of my microservices pom.xml

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.xyz.abc</groupId>
       <artifactId>somefunction</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But on an external server, when I try to install the jar using the command `mvn install:install-file -DlocalRepositoryPath=/home/sandesha-server/.m2/repository -DcreateChecksum=true -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/home/******/third-party.jar -DgroupId=com.xyz.abc -DartifactId=somefunction -Dversion=1.0`, it throws me the below error,

> Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sandesha:mymicroservice:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.xyz.abc:somefunction:jar:1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

I can see the jar being installed in `.m2`. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you try forcing the update?

Comment: take a look at this link: https://techexpertise.medium.com/installing-third-party-jars-to-a-maven-project-1-4c90de6f307a

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Nope. on server via linux terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can try to resolve the depencies of your project. Launch the following command at the root of you project:

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

Comment: It is giving the same error. I had run purgeLocalRepository before. Will that affect anything?

Comment: Check in your local repository if you library is actually present. Go in the directory configured on your maven, in com/xyz/abc. you should see a jar file and other files.

Comment: It is present in the local repo